# how to pass json with wwwform in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a newbie in unity.

i want to send a post request having following json data in unity

```
**url** = "http://index.php"

**sampple json** = {"id":"100","name":"abc"}
```

I am using C#

can anyone provide me a solution for this?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i've working with something like this:

```
    public class RequestConnectionManager : Manager<RequestConnectionManager>
    {

    public int maxSubmissionAttempts = 3;

    public Coroutine post() {
                WWWForm playForm = new WWWForm();
                playForm.AddField("id", myJson.id);
                playForm.AddField("name", myJson.name);

                Post playPost = new Post("http://index.php", playForm, maxSubmissionAttempts, this);
                return StartCoroutine(PostWorker(playPost));
            }

    private IEnumerator PostWorker(Post playPost)
        {
            yield return null;
            yield return playPost.Submit();

            Debug.Log(playPost.Response);
            if (playPost.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBoxManager.Instance.Show("Error: " + playPost.Error, "Error", MessageBoxManager.OKCancelOptionLabels, MessageOptions.Ok);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    //do whatever you want in here
                    //Hashtable response = JsonReader.Deserialize<Hashtable>(playPost.Response);
                    //Debug.Log("UNITY LOG..." + response);

                }
                catch (JsonDeserializationException jsExc)
                {
                    Debug.Log(jsExc.Message);
                    Debug.Log(playPost.Response);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Debug.Log(exc.Message);
                    Debug.Log(playPost.Response);
                }

            }
        }

    }

//As for the Manager class...

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


// I wonder what the constraint where TManager : Singleton<TManager> would produce...
public class Manager<TManager> : SingletonW<TManager> where TManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    override protected void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps! =)

Comment: But how can I use json binary data with it?

Answer (score 2):

I've done for doing this below. Let's go : ==>

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class btnGetData : MonoBehaviour {
 void Start()
 {
     gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
 }
 IEnumerator WaitForWWW(WWW www)
 {
     yield return www;


     string txt = "";
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
         txt = www.text;  //text of success
     else
         txt = www.error;  //error
     GameObject.Find("Txtdemo").GetComponent<Text>().text =  "++++++\n\n" + txt;
 }
 void TaskOnClick()
 {
     try
     {
         GameObject.Find("Txtdemo").GetComponent<Text>().text = "starting..";   
         string ourPostData = "{\"plan\":\"TESTA02\"";
         Dictionary<string,string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
         //byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes();
         byte[] pData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ourPostData.ToCharArray());
         ///POST by IIS hosting...
         WWW api = new WWW("http://192.168.1.120/si_aoi/api/total", pData, headers);
         ///GET by IIS hosting...
         ///WWW api = new WWW("http://192.168.1.120/si_aoi/api/total?dynamix={\"plan\":\"TESTA02\"");
         StartCoroutine(WaitForWWW(api));
     }
     catch (UnityException ex) { Debug.Log(ex.Message); }
 } 
}
```

Comment: It seems that `WWW` is `Obsolete`.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html