# making a REST calls from unity3d - Need to pass JSON object using HTTPWebRequest

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to make a REST call in unity3d? especially POST method. I have tried with GET request. Pls see the below get request. so i need to write POST request in Unity3d. The post rquest should be in JSON format. I tried with below code. It's hit the my service but the receiving JSON object is null. Hope your support.

```
var httpWebReq = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:6091/UserService.svc/RegisterUser/") as HttpWebRequest;

        httpWebReq.ContentType = "text/json;charset=utf-8";
        httpWebReq.Method= "POST";  

        using(var streamWriter  = new StreamWriter(httpWebReq.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string user = "{UserID:0," +
                            "Email:'ruwan@gmail.com'," +
                            "Password:'ruwan123'," +
                            "NickName:'ruwa'," +
                            "Age:35" +
                            "}";                        

            byte[] formData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user);
            httpWebReq.ContentLength = formData.Length;

            streamWriter.Write(formData);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebReq.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            //Now you have your response.
            //or false depending on information in the response
            Debug.Log(responseText);            
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass json with wwwform in unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492089/how-to-pass-json-with-wwwform-in-unity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution thanks to all for help.
Actually the easiest way to make rest call for WCF is we have to add the Newtonsoft.Json. Finally my code is-

GET --

WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

```
        myWebClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/json");

        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Room[] >(new WebClient().DownloadString("Your URL"));

        List<yourclass> test1= new List<yourclass>();

        foreach (var test in json)
        {
            test1.Add(new yourclass()
                      {
                yourclass.property1 = test.property1                    
        });
        }

        Debug.Log(test1);
```

POST---
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

```
        var Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                                                     {
            YourProperty= 0


        }, new JsonSerializerSettings() { Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None });

        myWebClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/json");
        string responsebody = myWebClient.UploadString("Your URL", "POST", Test );

        //if(responsebody == true)
        Debug.Log(responsebody);
```

Answer (score 2):

use [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) for GET,

use [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) with [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) for POST.